# Why are these 2 methods ambiguous

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm getting an error about my functions being ambiguous

> The current request for action 'Index' on controller type
>   'ProductController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(bconn.ui.Models.Vm, Int32, Int32) on
>   type bconn.ui.Controllers.ProductController
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(System.String, System.String) on
>   type bconn.ui.Controllers.ProductController

As you can see, one controller has the following signature

```
public ActionResult Index(Vm model, int startIndex, int pageSize)
```

And the other

```
public ActionResult Index(string selected, string nothing)
```

Due to the fact that one has `int` values, which are not nullable, I can't see how any ambiguity is here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not like in a regular class. When you have action methods, you can't overload them unless you use `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]` attributes to distinguish between them.

For instance, you need to have:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(Vm model, int startIndex, int pageSize) 
{
    ...
}
```

And

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string selected, string nothing)
{
    ...
}
```